# wingpanel freeze when volume-control button is clicked

Tags: wingpanel

today I installed elementary OS (Hera) on my physical hard drive after weeks of tinkering around in a virtual machine:)

Unfortunately I ran into a problem after setting up everything:

Every time I click on the volume button in the top right corner the system freezes. I can see and move the mouse but I can't click on anything.
Luckily it is possible to "win + T" or "ctrl + alt + F1" into a terminal and killing the "wingpanel" process (googled it) solves the issue.

There is no problem with anything else and I usually change the volume via a knob on my keyboard but I wonder if there is a patch around.

I googled at least an hour and didn't find this exact scenario. I would provide a report if neccessary but I have no idea how^^. I could't find any log file either.

(Sorry for the double post)

best regards

edit:

I found out that "killall spotify" (its a snap package) solved the problem. Just to reproduce I started spotify again but clicking the volume button didnt freeze the system again. 
Maybe the system as just overloaded with all those snaps because I installed and ran everything without really "closing" the programs.

Sorry that long post :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem happens when Spotify(snap) is running, try installing Spotify with the following instructions:

Uninstall Spotify from snap with `sudo snap remove spotify` or in the snap store.

Install curl: `sudo apt install curl`

Run: `curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

Then run: `echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

Finally: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spotify-client`

Reboot and try using Spotify again.

This info was taken from the official [Spotify Webpage for Linux](https://www.spotify.com/co/download/linux/)